# Using a Queue of Supplier<Boolean> to control flow

Tags: java

I have a sequence of methods which should only be called if the previous returned successfully. If a method is successful it returns true, otherwise it returns false. Please tell me what you think of this approach, and if there is a standard/better way to accomplish the same thing.

```
public class EventParser {
    private ApiResponseParser parser;
    private EventResponse response;

    private Entities entities;

    public EventParser(ApiResponseParser parser) {
        this.parser = parser;
        this.response = parser.getEventResponse();
    }

    public boolean parse() {
        Queue<Supplier<Boolean>> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.add(() -> parseEntities());
        q.add(() -> parseTournament());
        q.add(() -> parseVideogame());
        q.add(() -> parseEvent());  
        q.add(() -> parsePhases());
        q.add(() -> parseGroups());

        while(!q.isEmpty()) {
            if(!q.poll().get()) {           
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * Suppliers
     */
    private boolean parseEntities() {
        entities = response.getEntities();
        if(entities == null) { 
            printError("Event Entities null");          
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private boolean parseTournament() {
        Tournament tournament;
        if((tournament = entities.getTournament()) == null) {
            printError("Tournament null");
            return false;
        }
        tournament.setSlug(parser.getSlug());
        parser.setTournament(tournament);
        return true;
    }
    private boolean parseVideogame() {
        if(entities.getVideogame() == null) {
            printError("Videogames null");
            return false;
        }
        Videogame videogame = entities.getVideogame().stream()
                .filter(vg -> vg.getId().intValue() == Constants.VIDEO_GAME_ID_MELEE.intValue())
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
        if(videogame == null) {
            printError("Melee isn't in the list of videogames.");
            return false;
        }
        parser.setVideoGame(videogame);
        return true;
    }
    private boolean parseEvent() {
        if(entities.getEvent() == null) {
            printError("Event null");
            return false;
        }

        Event event = entities.getEvent().stream()
            .filter(ev -> validEventName(ev.getName()))
            .map(ev -> ev.withTournament(parser.getTournament()).withVideogame(parser.getVideogame()))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
        if(event == null) {
            printError("This tournament doesn't have melee singles.");
            return false;
        }
        parser.setEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
    private boolean parsePhases() {
        Event event = parser.getEvent();
        try {
            Set<Phase> phases = entities.getPhase().stream()
                    .filter(phase -> phase.getEventId().intValue() == event.getId().intValue())
                    .map(phase -> phase.withEvent(event))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            parser.setPhases(phases);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            printError(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private boolean parseGroups() {
        Map<Integer, Phase> phaseMap = parser.getPhases().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Phase::getId, phase -> phase));
        try {
            Set<Group> groups = entities.getGroups().stream()
                    .filter(group -> phaseMap.containsKey(group.getPhaseId()))
                    .map(group -> group.withPhase(phaseMap.get(group.getPhaseId())))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            parser.setGroups(groups);
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            printError(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean validEventName(String name) {
        name = name.toLowerCase();
        return name.contains("melee") && name.contains("singles");
    }

    private void printError(String errorMessage) {
        System.err.println(String.format("\tERROR parsing Event with slug %s: %s", parser.getSlug().getId(), errorMessage));
    }
}
```

- I'm unsure whether to use `Supplier<Boolean>` versus `Callable<Boolean>`
- I'm really, really uncertain about how to handle exceptions

Criticism is appreciated.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty figuring out what this code is actually supposed to do. So there is some object `entities` that contains a tournament, a number of videogames, a number of events, a number of phases and a number of groups. And the aim of this code is to find a valid combination of a videogame, an event, a phase and a group and associate this combination with a tournament?

Comment: And does `Event.withTournament` and `Event.withVideogame` affect the event id, so that, in `parsePhases()`, you are in effect looking for a phase that somehow corresponds to the video game or the tournament?

Comment: They are POJO representations of JSON responses from an API. Each Tournament has Events which can be different games, 1v1, 2v2, etc. I'm interested in 1v1 in a certain game. Each Event has Phases (Pools, Top 64, Top 8, etc). Each Phase has Groups (basically just brackets). You can find out more [here](https://help.smash.gg/hc/en-us/articles/217471947-API-Access). And if you're interested, I can post 2 more classes -- `ApiResponseParser` and `GroupParser`. I just thought that may be too much to include in something like this. Either way, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: The reason I asked is that it seems that these methods only make sense when called in the order you call them. For example, `parseTournament()` assumes that `entities` has already been assigned a value. But a method does not know when it is called, so it should not make any assumptions about state it depends on. I was thinking that it might be better to redesign these methods, maybe by making them accept the state they depend on as a parameter and return the queried entity instead of modifying an object's state. It seems `parseTournament` and `parseVideogame` only depend on `entities`, […]

Comment: […] so they could just accept `entities` as a parameter. `parseEvent` looks like it depends on both the tournament and the video game, so it could accept these two as parameters. But I'm not sure whether this is really what's happening behind your code. For example, if the purpose of this code is to build a query string or something, then each method would indeed depend on all other methods that come before it, so the approach described above would not work.